# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, hibernate

Preciso de ajuda a tentar esclarecer estes 2 erros:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.<init>(InflaterInputStream.java:88)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.<init>(ZipFile.java:394)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:375)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:447)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:162)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver.resolveInHibernateNamespace(DTDEntityResolver.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver.resolveOnClassPath(DTDEntityResolver.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DTDEntityResolver.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(EJB3DTDEntityResolver.java:59)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:110)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:988)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:488)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.add(Configuration.java:657)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2188)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2140)
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 48 minutes 37 seconds)
```

E este:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3326)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.sql.SelectFragment.toFragmentString(SelectFragment.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.propertySelectFragment(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1458)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.selectFragment(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initStatementString(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initStatementString(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initAll(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.loader.AbstractEntityJoinWalker.initAll(AbstractEntityJoinWalker.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.CascadeEntityJoinWalker.<init>(CascadeEntityJoinWalker.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.CascadeEntityLoader.<init>(CascadeEntityLoader.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3891)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3828)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.postInstantiate(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:1018)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1790)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1861)
    at DAO.GenericDao.getSession(GenericDao.java:28)
    at DAO.ProdutoDao.findProdutoByNumero(ProdutoDao.java:39)
    at Service.ProdutoController.findProdutoByNumero(ProdutoController.java:37)
    at Service.ServidorService.getValoresAndon(ServidorService.java:718)
    at Service.ServidorService$1.run(ServidorService.java:141)
set 10, 2014 11:44:23 AM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 37 minutes 0 seconds)
```

Estes erros apareceram depois de começar a usar o `hibernate` e eu gostava de perceber se é possível saber qual o `objecto` que está a encher a memoria?
Tudo o que estou a fazer com o `hibernate` funciona bem mas passando uns minutos estoura.

Não tenho experiência em usar o `hibernate`
Quanto a questão de aumentar a memoria já fiz(-Xmx128m e mais quantidade até e não resolveu)

**EDIT**

```
private void threadControllerRun() {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    getValoresAndon();
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServidorService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Este é a onde chamo a função que penso que dá o erro(é a função "principal") mas acho que por ai não dá para perceber o erro

Estive a ver o código que tenho do meu DAO e não sei porquê mas acho que esta implementação não está correta, isto porque sempre que vou fazer alguma coisa a BD ele cria uma nova sessão, estou certo ou errado? Pode ser isto que me arrebenta com a memória?

```
public Session getSession() {

    Configuration cfg= new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sessionfactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    session=sessionfactory.openSession();

    return this.session;
}
```

Comment: Clique em [edit] e adicione o código do método run() da sua classe ServidorService. Acredito que isso nos ajudará a te ajudar.

Comment: Ja adicionei, o método run que chama a função onde penso que dá o erro, nao sei se era este metodo, porque tenho varios.

Comment: Para explicar melhor este programa é um servidor que quando inicia cria uma thread para gerir sockets (clientes que vao ficar ligados a ele para receber informação) e depois tem outra que processa toda essa informação para enviar para eles e é nessa que tenho o problema

Comment: Não sei se tens conhecimentos com o hibernate mas o que falo em cima não tem um pouco de lógica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que está acontecendo é que existem muitas conexões em gerenciamento na memoria. Uma solução é fechar a sessão com `session.close()` a cada vez que terminar de usa-la um método que se comunique com o bd, e reabri-la quando necessário.

A melhor solução, porém, é transformar essa classe utilitária fornecedora de session em um Singleton, o que faria ela ter apenas UMA instância da Session, e quando necessário, não criaria outra, nem mesmo configuraria de novo, só repassaria, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
//Irrelevante à definição da SESSAO, mas necessário para não instanciação da classe 
//utilitária fornecedora
private Construtor(){}

//Variável estática;
private static Session SESSAO;

//Campo estatico que define o valor da SESSAO;
static {
    Configuration cfg= new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sessionfactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    return SESSAO = sessionfactory.openSession();
}

//Método de retorno da SESSAO
public static Session getSession(){
    return SESSAO;
}
```

**EDIT**

O que coloquei acima estava um pouco errado, pois ainda não havia construido nenhuma vez a váriavel `SESSAO`, já corrigi o problema.

**EDIT**

Como dito, o construtor não é a melhor abordagem, acabei confundindo na hora da criação, e peço pro autor da Pergunta rever o mérito de melhor resposta.
Estou corrigindo e colocando uma visão que acho estar correta.

Comment: E como você conseguiria uma instância dessa classe para acessar o método `getSession`? Setar valor da variável estática `SESSAO` pelo construtor não me parece a abordagem correta. Recomendo utilizar ao menos um [Singleton](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) para isso.

Comment: Entendi o que vc quis dizer. Corrigindo

Comment: Mas como você chamaria o método `getSession`? Outra coisa, também acho que `this = new Construtor()` não é uma sentença válida em Java, já que o `this` não é uma variável e sim, uma palavra reservada que contém a referência da instância da classe onde o código se encontra.

Comment: Sim, fez bem em observar isso, acabei corrigindo o código, e colocando uma explicação, veja se está adequado. E o `this = new Construtor()` nem serviria, já que estou tentando criar `Singletons` e ele criaria uma nova `SESSAO` toda vez que fosse chamada.

Comment: Se bem que eu nunca usei `static{}`, sei para que serve, mas não tenho proximidade.

Comment: Ah, agora ficou claro :). Apenas uma observação: Abrir a sessão em um bloco `static` fará com que a sessão seja aberta no momento que o [ClassLoader](http://javafree.uol.com.br/artigo/876400/ClassLoader-Desmitificado.html) carregar essa classe. Volto a recomendar ao menos o uso do padrão [Singleton](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton). Mas isso é só uma sugestão de boa prática. Acredito que o exemplo atual responde a pergunta corretamente :D